# Multiple Motors and one H bridge

Tags: motor

I am trying to make one H bridge for four identical motors. I do not want to make more than one H bridge by any means. I got a way to do that but I need your recommendation. I am going to make all the motors in parallel to each other so that the current, that comes from one branch in the H bridge, splits apart to all the four motors.

**Specifications:**

Each one of those four motors has the following features:

"Voltage:DC 6V
Current:120MA
Reduction rate:48:1
RPM (With tire):240

Motor Weight (g):50
Motor Size:70mm*22mm*18mm"

Purpose of use: Building a small robot that moves with 4 wheels.
Each wheel is with one motor.
Sounds a good idea? Tell me.

Comment: The slightest imbalance in the motors' characteristics will make things... interesting.

Comment: More information will  get more useful answers. What power, what voltages, what application, why 4 motors, how crucial is motor response matching?, ...? | Series resistor per motro will help balance them - OK for small motors.

Comment: @Russell McMahon Even without the H bridge, we will get response matching issues and we are gonna fix that. Add to that the H bridge's matching issues ones as well. So, we really need to minimize that for quality purposes.

Comment: Imbalance is liable to always exist. The motors MAY track each other on a smooth flat surface but any unevenness in loading will imbalance the distance travelled by each motor.

Comment: How do propose to steer your robot?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast By "differential steering". This is why we designed the robot to be with 4 motors. ( we could do with 2 motors i think but it needs some mechanical skills that i do not like to go with).

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams this is why we want your recommendation bec no body wants to lose money that is enough for 3 days' dinner.

Comment: If you are driving all 4 motors identically, how will you get the differential part? I'm assuming 1 motor per wheel.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Your point is very logical. We have two phases in this project. 1- To get the robot moving backward/forward (related to my question). 2- Steering. For 2, I think we can "interfere" with each motor by creating a  system that is connected with the micro-controller. But, here it is, 2 depends on 1. If one is perfect, two can be done in my opinion.(it is edited).

Comment: Why the aversion to giving each motor its own Hbridge?  You can get two in a single IC so you only need two ICs.

Comment: @ Kevin White That is correct. I heard about ICs that can do that. However, we decided to do the circuitry from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general concept I don't see any problems, as long as you don't expect the robot to move in a perfectly straight line. It may well be pretty good, but you seem to be aware of the problem of motor/wheel matching.

And I presume you are aware that the motors on the left side must be wired the reverse of the motors on the right.

When you graduate to differential steering, you will need 2 bridges. Get used to it. Actually, since you are talking about 4 motors I assume you have a 4-wheel vehicle with a motor on each wheel. Be aware that differential steering works very poorly on 4-wheel vehicles.

Comment: I would say *as long as you don't expect the robot to move in anything reproducible, and certainly not in a straight line*.